# Not able to create a login form in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have to create a basic `Login Form` in `Swing` on `JButton` `ActionListner`. So i wrote the following code:

```
private void Balance() throws IOException {
 getContentPane().removeAll();
 JPanel test = new JPanel();
 JLabel singin = new JLabel();
 javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon(
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20476478/Capture.PNG",
    "a pretty but meaningless splat");
 singin.setIcon(icon);
 test.add(singin);
 getContentPane().add(test);
 repaint();
 printAll(getGraphics());
}
```

It create the UI like below:

[image: sample]

```
But i am looking for this:
```

[image: I want like this]

I tried it a lot but not able to fit the dimension like above one. I just started to learn the `Swing`

Comment: You might use a `CardLayout` for this task.  The 1st card in the layout would be blank, after log-in flip to the card with Email address/password & log-in button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/FormLayoutDefaultFormBuilderExample1.htm) is an example.

Comment: can i add the FormLayout in JPanel?

Comment: Is `import com.jgoodies.forms.builder.DefaultFormBuilder;` jgoodies is jar?

Comment: You can download the example from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/FormLayoutDefaultFormBuilderExample1.htm)